# AsposeX - accessing object within object

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

### Basic Question

How do we access a variable within a variable using asposeX word template variable notation?

### Description

I have the following java class structure:

```
    @Data
public static class MyCase {
        private User caseHandler = new User();      
    }

    @Data
   public static class User implements Serializable {
  private String fullName;
}
```

And I was trying the following within an AsposeX word template:

```
  <<foreach [c in root]>> 
  << [c.caseHandler.fullName] >> 
  <</foreach>>
```

But the following was failing.

Currently the below is working for me:

```
   <<foreach [c in root]>> 


<<foreach [in c.caseHandler]>>

<<[fullname]>>  

<</foreach>>


      <</foreach>>
```

**Is there a more efficient way to reference fullName within `c.caseHandler`?**

Comment: You are using the correct way for Master-Detail template syntax. If caseHandler has only one record, you can use extension method of IEnumerable<T> like <<[c.caseHandler.First().fullName]>>. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was mentioned by Tahir was to use `first()`.

There is a list of extension enumeration methods at:

https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsjava/Appendix+A.+Enumeration+Extension+Methods

Comment: The first() extension method can be used if you want to get the first record of caseHandler.